# Issue with CoreData and photos in iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, core-data, icloud

I have an issue. 
My app is storing - data with CoreData (in Model.sqlite file) and user created photos as jpgs. 
It all is stored in Documents directory. 
I managed to store my database in iCloud (but it is still buggy), but i have no idea how to store both database and photos in iCloud. 
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i never used iCloud synch but this could help answer your question.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html

Comment: I read it. But still I don't know how to connect both core data and user files

Comment: What is stored to CoreData?

Comment: I store saved data about receipts in CoreData, and photos in Documents directory

Comment: So if your app is supporting iCloud, than your CoreData should do it automaticaly for you. Just check if you have in your coreData attributes turn on external storage.

Comment: So, After all comments : in iPhone, in Documents directory, I'm storing sqlite database (with records about receipts) and photos saved along with database in Documents dir. How to back it all up to iCloud and retrieve?